# Why does Spring's PropertySource throw a FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to load a properties file using Spring, that is located in my `WEB-INF` folder.

I am receiving the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to parse configuration class [com.elastictest.config.ProdConfig];
>   nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   \WEB-INF\config\prod.properties (The system cannot find the path
>   specified)

Here is my Production Configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
@PropertySource("file:${prodPropertiesFile}")
public class ProdConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

Here is my web.xml declaration:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>prodPropertiesFile</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/prod.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have opened the war and verified that the properties file is there under WEB-INF/config folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

The [locations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html#value--) you specify within the [`@PropertySource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) annotation are processed by a [`ResourceLoader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html). In this case, that will be your [`AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html), since this is a web application and you want to use an annotation configuration.

As a `ResourceLoader` implementation, `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` knows how to resolve *location* values to find and initialize [`Resource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) objects. It uses these to create [`ResourcePropertySource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/ResourcePropertySource.html) objects which are used in property resolution.

The *location* value resolution follows a few steps:

- If it starts with a `/`, it's interpreted as a servlet context resource and Spring attempts to retrieve it through [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).
- If it starts with `classpath:`, it's interpreted as a classpath resource and Spring tries to retrieve it through [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-), given an appropriate `ClassLoader`.
- Otherwise, it defers resolution to a [`UrlResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/UrlResource.html) which uses the `URL` to locate a resource. Its javadoc states

  > Supports resolution as a `URL` and also as a `File` in case of the `"file:"` protocol.

In your case, you prefixed your location with `file:` so Spring tried to use the `UrlResource`. Your path had a leading `/` which the file system will consider as the beginning of an absolute path. You obviously don't have a file at that location, `/WEB-INF/config/prod.properties`.

If you use a `classpath:` prefix as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40540838/438154), then you must make sure that `/WEB-INF/config/prod.properties` is on the classpath. That's a very uncommon thing to put on the classpath, so I don't recommend it.

Finally, as you've found out, you could use

```
@PropertySource("/WEB-INF/config/prod.properties")
// or to support your property
@PropertySource("${prodPropertiesFile}")
```

which will attempt to retrieve a resource through the `ServletContext`. Its javadoc states

> The path must begin with a `/` and is interpreted as relative to the current context root

Your `WEB-INF` folder will be in the context root (basically a directory chosen for your Servlet container as the root of your web application) and so the resource will be found and used.

---

You can read more about `Resource` in the official documentation, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resource), and about the `ResourceLoader` process, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-resources).

Comment: Great explanation for OP and me too. I'm not good that much of writing and explanation :)

Answer (score -1):

No need web.xml declaration. Try like this

```
@PropertySource(name="prodPropertiesFile", value="classpath:/WEB-INF/config/prod.properties")
public class ProdConfig {
}
```

Comment: If I remove the wen.xml declaration for the context param, what will prodPropertiesFile refer to

Comment: Do you try my way?No need in spring 4.You have name and value.You can use name.Check http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Comment: yes, I tried it, same result. I'm really stumped with this one

Comment: What difference will your suggestion make? What was wrong with their attempt? What is correct about yours? Why do you assume that resource is on the `classpath`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The exception is FileNotFound exception right. I thought the program cannot load properties file  properly. So how do think about this?

Comment: I've posted an answer that details everything. That's what I was asking you to do with your answer., explain why theirs doesn't work and why yours will. In their case, I don't think it will. They haven't shown any evidence that `/WEB-INF/config/prod.properties` would be on the classpath and I don't see why they would.

Answer (score -2):

It turned out to be simpler than I was making it:

```
@PropertySource("/WEB-INF/config/prod.properties")
```